# How to authenticate to microsoft active directory through iOS App?

Tags: ios5, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am to authenticate username and password credentials to a Active Directory through the iOS App?

I know that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877233/using-ldap-for-authentication-in-ios) instructs us to include the openldap in the project, BUT [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651875/how-to-authenticate-to-active-directory-using-ios-app?answertab=oldest#tab-top) here has indicated that there are inbuilt ldap protocol that I can use to connect with the Active Directory using PHP.

Can somebody shed light on both of the topics, and pick one which would be useful for the current version of XCode.

And also, are there any examples of this that any user can share?

P.S: This is my first question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are exposing your domain on the Internet, you'll need some sort of service layer. If you know php, that is probably a good route to go. Then, from the iOS application, you simply call the operations exposed through your php server. For creating the service, you may want to look into an [ldap library for php](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/).