# How do i integrate the Microsoft's Active Directory in my iPhone app to authenticate the user while Login

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, active-directory

I have searched a lot for integrating AD for authenticating a user while login, I've read these pages :

1. http://www.macworld.com/article/1056791/activedirectory, which gives me the basic info but not the exact solution.
2. Later on while R and D i come to the post on Stack Overflow [How to authenticate to Active Directory using iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651875/how-to-authenticate-to-active-directory-using-ios-app), which showed me the solution based on PHP server page, but I want to authenticate that user from my app itself.

How can I do this correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// Hi everyone i solved this problem with the .NET SOAP service, my colleague has written that web service which needs the two parameters USERNAME and PASSWORD which we want to authenticate from Active Directory, Once we call that web service along with the parameters USERNAME and PASSWORD it returns us TRUE if the user is registered with the active directory or returns the FALSE.  The authentication of the Active Directory user is very easy from .NET than that of from Objective-C.

Comment: Then you are authenticating with Basic Authentication, not with AD. "Authenticate with AD" implies using the Kerberos token and nothing else.

Comment: thanx Henrik i googling for the kerberos tokens to authenticate with AD and today its DONE!!