# Single sign-on in iPad applications - objective c

Tags: objective-c, ipad, single-sign-on

I want to implement single-sign on by using the active directory available in our organization in one of the iPad application we are developing. It should be similar to the Single sign on which we do in web applications. We are using VPN connection to connect to the organization's  intranet in the iPad. 
Is there a way that we can authenticate and authorize connecting to the active directory of the organization in an iPad app ? Any advise on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: you might want to take a look at [How do i integrate the Microsoft's Active Directory in my iPhone app to authenticate the user while Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405470/how-do-i-integrate-the-microsofts-active-directory-in-my-iphone-app-to-authenti)

Comment: The solution given in the link uses PHP .... Is there any way that to authenticate directly with the active directory from the iPad app ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help in achieving the same in objective C..

[EWS - How to pass credentials for Autodiscover - ios, cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766985/ews-how-to-pass-credentials-for-autodiscover-ios-cocoa)

Hope this helps you..