# EWS - How to pass credentials for Autodiscover - ios, cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

After a lot of searching around, am posting this issue.

Here is the problem..

I am using EWS for imporing contact to a MAc Application using AutoDiscover.

Here goes my XML Request

```
      NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<Autodiscover xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/requestschema/2006/\">"
                         "<Request>"
                         "<EMailAddress>%@</EMailAddress>"
                         "<AcceptableResponseSchema>"
                         "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a"
                         "</AcceptableResponseSchema>"
                         "</Request>"
                         "</Autodiscover>",self.emailId.stringValue];
NSLog(@"%@",soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://<domainname>/EWS/Exchange.asmx"];
```

The above is just the snippet. Have passed the other headers intact.

My problem is where exactly to pass the user credential as they pass in C# as below

```
 ExchangeServiceBinding esb = new ExchangeServiceBinding();
 esb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<username>", "<password>", "<domain>");
```

I tried using challenge authentication and also tried using sending it in header authorisation. But no luck.

Any help in achieving this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There was a problem in AutoDiscover, so using direct URL - https://<domainname>/EWS/Exchange.asmx

Now the request (with soapAction) is returning the wsdl for all soapAction with 200. Am also using Impersonation. Anybody knows what might be the problem..

Comment: I'm having a wsdl for EWS integration to iOS. Could you please guide me how to move ahead and what is required to get it done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its all about constructing the proper XML request to EWS. That's it..

Use https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/ to fetch mail, contact, calendar to test.

Check the request it generates, copy the same in your header portion of XML.

It works like breeze..

Posting this to save some of the non-window developer's time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, challenge authentification works for Exchange Web Services. EWS uses ServerTrust and NTLM authentication.
Implement NSURLConnectionDelegate methods in such way:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ( challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 )
    {
        // handle authentication error here, e.g. NSError *authError = ...;
        return;
    }

    // username and password should be stored as ivars.
    NSString *username = @"your_username";
    NSString *password = @"your_password";

    NSURLCredential *urlCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    [challenge.sender useCredential:urlCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}


- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    // Should return YES for NTLM and ServerTrust methods.
    NSString *authMethod = protectionSpace.authenticationMethod;
    return ([authMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust] ||
            [authMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM] );
}
```

Comment: is there any sample project or code available to connect news with auto discover and send mail. Im looking for some sample codes to help me